# Google Sheets; Finding the first cell to contain 0 in a column where the row number is > the row number generated in another formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a document in Google sheets that produces the start and end times where a number of people are in a section. I was able to produce a grid, but I can't seem to find a formula for calculating end times that occur after the start time.

| Time | Section1 | Section2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9:00am | 1 | 0 |
| 9:30am | 1 | 0 |
| 10:00am | 1 | 1 |
| 10:30am | 0 | 1 |

I want to make a series of formulas that list the start and end times when people are present in a section.

1. (Start time) Find the first cell to **not contain** 0 and return the value in column A {I have found a formula for this step}
2. (End time) Find the first cell to **contain 0** *where the row number is greater than the row number of the previous start time* and return the value in column A

For the first part, I can find the start time with the formula

```
=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A,(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B$2:$B>0,0),0))))
```

But when I try to adapt it to the end time by changing the greater than (>) to equals (=), it gives me the first time there is a zero regardless of if it occurs before the start time. I feel like adding some kind of row check will be necessary to fix this, but I'm not sure how. I would really rather not learn Google API if at all possible,

Comment: Welcome! Are you expecting to find the first 0 after a 1 or a list of start and end time?

Comment: Could you share a sample result you want to get based on the sample sheet data you have shared on your question?

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer to have the result reference the time column. So the end time formula for section 1 would be "10:00am" and the end time result of Section2 would be "10:30am".  I do have to worry about gaps in the larger sheet, but I figure that I could adapt any end time formula to find additional start times. If it helps, I have 6 columns prepared for this: Start 1, End 1, Start 2, End 2, Start 3, End 3

Comment: This seems it is not a trivial process. Would you prefer using a **custom Google Sheet function** via scripting to achieve your goal like [this](https://imgur.com/a/tAYTTy2)?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just to find the first 0 after a 1, you could benefit from the use of INDEX and MATCH to create a range that goes from the first 1 to the last row and look the 0 in that range. That is: `INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(1,B2:B,0)):INDEX(B2:B,ROWS(B2:B))` So, inserted in the whole formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:A,MATCH(1,B2:B,0)  +  MATCH(0, INDEX(B2:B,MATCH(1,B2:B,0)):INDEX(B2:B,ROWS(B2:B)) ,0)-1)
```